# Memory retainment issue

Tags: ios

I am writing an iOS app with a navigator controller and a base class with an array of Vaccines.

```
@synthesize vaccines;

self.vaccines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

Vaccine *v = [[Vaccine alloc] init];
[v setVaxName: [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"Anthrax" ]];
[v setAdultDescr: [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"" ]];
[v setPed06Descr: [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"" ]];
[v setPed718Descr: [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"" ]];
[v setPedCatchDescr: [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"" ]];
[self.vaccines addObject:v];
[v release];
```

I use this method in my delegate class to access the vaccine's name:

```
- (NSString *) getVaccineName: (NSInteger) i
{
if ([vaccines count] > i)
{
    return [[vaccines objectAtIndex:i] getVaxName];
}
return @"";
}
```

I use a method in class Vaccine to access the name.

```
(NSMutableString *) getVaxName
{
    return vaxname;
}
```

Upon creation, vaccines is in tact and returns "Anthrax." However, when I go to another page, I call:

```
NSString *str = [delegate getVaccineName: 0];
```

This returns garbage.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like the base class isn't persisting as long as you need it to.  Would a singleton be useful here?

Comment: after your 'self.vaccines = [[NSMutableArray...' add this: 'NSLog(@"init array-> %@",self)' and then before you attempt to read the vaccine name do this: 'NSLog(@"read array -> %@",delegate)'. Note how many times those are logged, the order, and of course the output.

Comment: Upon further inspection, the program sometimes throws the following exception:

2011-12-19 17:01:21.810 Immunizations[30668:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSMachPort isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7042200'

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Vaccine class as follow:

```
// Vaccine.h
@interface Vaccine: NSObject {
    NSString *vaxName;
    NSString *adultDescr;
    // crete the other instance variables
}
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *vaxName;
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *adultDescr;
// add the other accessor properties
@end

// Vaccine.m
@implementation Vaccine

@synthesize vaxName
@synthesize adultDescr
// synthesize the other properties

@end
```

At this point, you can modify the first snippet you provided as follow:

```
Vaccine *v = [[Vaccine alloc] init];
v.vaxName = @"name"; // its the same as [v setVaxName:@"name"];
v.adultDescr = @"descr";
// set the other properties
```

NSString is not a primitive type like int, float, etc.. It's an object. If you want to maintain it in memory you have to increment its retain count. Simply assigning it, it doesn't allow you to mantain it in memory. For further informations see: [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html)

Remember to release the memory in dealloc method for your Vaccine class:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   self.vaxName = nil;
   self.adultDescr = nil;
   // release the other properties
}
```

Following Hyperbole suggestion, it could be better to maintain your model (your vaccines array) in a singleton class, for example. Other solutions are also available (i.e. save/restore the model in NSUserDefaults, etc.). In this manner you could have access to it in any part within your application.

Answer (score 0):

What do your setter methods look like in the Vaccine class? At the moment you are assigning autoreleased objects to them, so if you are not retaining in the setter, this could produce the effect you are seeing.

In your accessors you are directly assigning the passed in value to an instance variable. This is still autoreleased and so will have disappeared by the time you come to access it. The simplest solution is to use properties and set values via the dot notation:

In your header:

```
@proprerty (nonatomic, copy) NSString *vaccineName;
```

In your implementation:

```
@synthesize vaccineName;
```

Then to set:

```
v.vaccineName = @"name";
```

You shouldn't be using mutable strings if the property you are assigning to is a string.

Comment: I'm only dealing with NSString's. The code is as follows.
    - (void) setVaxName: (NSString *)str
    {
        vaxname=str;
    }

Comment: That's your problem then. As I said, you are not retaining the strings. Either set them up as properties and use the synthesised accessor, or use the standard accessor format as I am about to put in my question.

Comment: This isn't the problem. I've set the strings up to be synthesized. I made a typo in my previous comment as I was typing off my head.

Comment: Your latest comment on the question is typical of a premature release situation - the memory has been reassigned to a different object and you still have the pointer to it and are treating it as a string. Without seeing your vaccine class there is no more to add.